# Torus and projective space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X = T^2 \sharp P^2 = 3P^2$. If a remove an interior point of $X$, I can retract the space onto the boundary. This new space is the wedge of three $S^1$?

Comment: Yes, I know. But in this particular case I have exactly three , right?

Comment: Right. Removing $n$ points from $\sharp_g\Bbb RP^2$ gives a non-compact manifold homotopy equivalent to the wedge of $g+n-1$ circles.